# Error while publishing Azure WebJob for "staging" enviroment

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2015, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs

### My Project Configuration:

I have a web application project (Visual Studio 2015 update 1 + c#) that includes an Azure Webjob. The Webjob is part of the project configuration. Looks like this (location: ProjName -> Properties -> webjobs_list.json):

```
{
  "$schema": "http://schemastore.org/schemas/json/webjobs-list.json",
  "WebJobs": [
    {
      "filePath": "../Jobs/XXX/XXX.csproj"
    }
  ]
}
```

### My Azure Configuration:

I created a new website ("Web app") and published (to "production" environment) my project. Working great. Including my webjob.

So far, all good. Now, I created a new environment (within my web app site) that called "Staging". Go back to my Visual studio project, download the newly created publish profile (staging) and publish it.

### The Problem

Visual studio refuse to publish my project to the staging environment with this error:

> An error occurred while creating the WebJob schedule: No website could
>   be found which matches the WebSiteName [XXX__stage] and
>   WebSiteUrl [http://XXX-stage.azurewebsites.net] supplied.

What the...? Why?
By publishing the same project to "Production" environment, it's prove that the project configuration is OK (including webjob).

Any solution for this strange?

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

There are some known issues with configuring the Azure Scheduler from Visual Studio. The suggested approach is to avoid the use of the Azure Scheduler, and instead use the newer CRON based scheduler feature described in the docs [here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/#CreateScheduledCRON).

Basically, you create the WebJobs as manual (not scheduled), and then add a `settings.job` to it with a CRON expression, e.g. to run every 15 minutes:

`{
    "schedule": "0 */15 * * * *"
}`

Going forward, this will be the default in VS.

Comment: Is this still the case to not use the Azure timer? Running VS 2015 Update 3 and it still defaults to the Azure timer so wondering if it's now fixed?

Comment: At this point, yes, it is still the case. I know the VS team is planning to change that, but I don't know when that will happen.